# Login failed after MSSQL database restore

Tags: sql-server

I have two instances of the same software written in C++/CLI on two different computers, each app connected to its own MSSQL server. I need to backup one of the databases and restore it on the other computer through the app. I backup the database with the following query:

```
BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON;
BACKUP DATABASE [DB_NAME]
TO DISK = N'[FILEPATH]'
WITH NAME = N'full-database-backup';
END;
```

While the restore query is the following:

```
USE [master];
ALTER DATABASE [DB_NAME] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
RESTORE DATABASE [DB_NAME] FROM DISK = N'[FILEPATH]'
WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY;
ALTER DATABASE [DB_NAME] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

After the restore I need to read the database again to refresh the data in the app, but when I try to open a new connection to the restored database it fails with the following error:

```
Cannot open database [DB_NAME] requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user '[USER_NAME]'.
```

I tried to use `sp_change_users_login` without success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add the full message (with `state`) from the SQL Server Error log

Comment: The database principals will be unlinked from the server principals, especially so if the database has been restored to a different instance or server. You'll probably need to go through the database principals and `alter user [user name] with login=[login name]` Ref: [ALTER USER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql)

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Windows or SQL Login? If you are using SQL Login, then even the login exist on the second server the SID is different so restored database do not match the login with user.

You can create SQL Login with the same password hash and sid by query the password hash and sid on the 1 server:

```
  select 
        name, 
        CONVERT(varchar(max), LOGINPROPERTY(name, 'PasswordHash'),1 ) [password hash], 
        CONVERT(varchar(max), sid, 1) [sid]  
  from sys.server_principals 
  where name like 'SQL_LOGIN'
```

and then on the second server create login with password hash and sid from the first one:

```
CREATE LOGIN mo_test WITH PASSWORD = [PasswordHash] HASHED, SID = [SID]
```

After that you should be able to do your backup and restore and user will always be mapped.